# AngularJS passing data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Not sure if anyone understand my requirements since I'm still new to AngularJs but how can I pass a data which is stored in angular's scope to PHP? I know if I would use it in html code I can access it by calling {{scope.data}} but how do I achieve this by passing it to PHP?

```
<td style="width: 5%" rowspan="2" valign="top">
      <?php echo BsHtml::imageRounded(Yii::app()->baseUrl . {{user.avatar}} ); ?>
     </td>
```

Thanks Guys...

Comment: Perhaps you can POST the values you would like to pass to another PHP script through JavaScript, the PHP script then would read the POST variables and does something with them. (e.g use jQuery.ajax to pass the variables to the PHP script)

Comment: in your controller you would use the `$http` service and call the `$http.post()` method with your data object as the 'data' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send data from javascript to php unless you submit a form or use ajax stuff.
Because while browser rendering a page, browser gets data from server, not vice versa.
In this case, angular js has its built-in service $http.

take a look at this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http

and simple answer for your problem

```
<td style="width: 5%" rowspan="2" valign="top">
    <?php echo BsHtml::imageRounded(Yii::app()->baseUrl)?>{{user.avatar}}
</td>
```